# Add default bootstrap attribute to HTML without manually writing all the attribute for quick demo purposes

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

This is a question for a lazy bone like me~ 
So in Bootstrap I can do something like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
</div>
```

And I can make very readable website. 
However, now in my hand is a large piece of pure HTML code that I want to do a very quick demo. Here a very small part of my pure HTML code:

```
<input type="button" value="I am a button ._." name="someName"/><br><br>
<input type="checkbox" value="You boy???" name="gender"/><br>
<input type="checkbox" value="You girl???" name="gender"/><br><br>
```

I want to use Bootstrap styling so that those HTML codes can be well styled, but at the same time I don't want to edit them one by one to just add "form-control" on each one of the input elements.
Is there anyway to apply the bootstrap default form styling, default color, default nav style and so on, all into my code without adding those attribute myself?

---

For example, I want my:

```
<input type="button" value="I am a button ._." name="someName"/><br><br>
```

To become:

```
<input  class="form-control" type="button" value="I am a button ._." name="someName"/><br><br>
```

Without me specifying the **form-control** class. 
 
Thank you!

Comment: in bootstrap i dont think so, you have to go some how manually change those

Comment: I also think that is impossible (at least with my current research finding), but maybe someone will have some tricks to make this works!

Comment: **Step 1:** Have a decent editor **Step 2:** Use the Search & Replace option

Comment: Thanks @OfirBaruch, your answer is suitable too, but I think I will use Rahul jQuery answer since I can remove the jQuery code and revert the HTML code back to the original pure HTML code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need write **GLOBAL CSS** for this solution or use jquery `window.load` function. For example:

**CSS solution.**

From Bootstrap 3: `.form-control`

```
.form-control {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,
    box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,
    -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    -moz-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,
    box-shadow ease-in-out .15s,
    -moz-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,
    box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,
    -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,
    box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,
    box-shadow ease-in-out .15s,
    -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s,
    -moz-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    color: #555;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
}
```

For global css:

```
input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="number"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="date"],
input[type="datetime-local"],
input[type="month"],
input[type="search"],
input[type="week"],
input[type="time"],
input[type="url"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="range"],
select{
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,
    box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,
    -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    -moz-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,
    box-shadow ease-in-out .15s,
    -moz-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,
    box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,
    -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,
    box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,
    box-shadow ease-in-out .15s,
    -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s,
    -moz-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    color: #555;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
}
```

jQuery solution:

```
$(window).on('load',function(){
    $('input[type=text],input[type=email],input[type=number],input[type=password],input[type=date],input[type=datetime-local],input[type=month],input[type=search],input[type=week],input[type=time],input[type=url],input[type=tel],input[type=range],select').addClass('form-control');
});
```

Check the `jQuery` snippet.

```js
$(window).on('load',function(){
    $('input[type=text],input[type=email],input[type=number],input[type=password],input[type=date],input[type=datetime-local],input[type=month],input[type=search],input[type=week],input[type=time],input[type=url],input[type=tel],input[type=range],select').addClass('form-control');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="email" />
  <input type="number" />
  <input type="password" />
  <input type="date" />
  <input type="datetime-local" />
  <input type="month" />
  <input type="search" />
  <input type="week" />
  <input type="time" />
  <input type="url" />
  <input type="tel" />
  <input type="range" />
  <select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I found this two way for without writing bootstrap attribute in `html`.

Other option have [jade](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jade)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jade

> Note: You can load anything by `JavaScript`. But you should be write
>   all attribute and tag in `JavaScript` file. (I think it's hard to
>   write). Otherwise you have no way to skip writing `tag` and
>   `attribute` in `html`

Comment: The Both options work great! Thank you very much :) Since it is a small project, so I don't think I will go through the trouble to learn Jade right now.